# Black screen, very common after Ubuntu 22.04 > 21.10 update

Tags: kernel, screen, 21.10, 22.10

It never came in the 22.04 version, nor with the 22.04 kernel that I booted into on 21.10.
At 21.10 kernel the problems began. At times were gone, but now again after the latest kernel update, the situation is painful.
When the black screen comes, I have to press ctrl+alt+f3 and tap that f3 and maybe also f4 and f3, then ctrl+alt+f2 and tap f2. However, the chaotic action eventually restores the session.
At the time of writing this, again this one froze when I opened this with gedit:
lshw:
escription: Display controller
product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
driver=i915
...
uname -r
5.19.0-43-generic (I was wondering if it wasI was wondering if it was a 5.15 kernel that worked flawlessly).

Comment: We no longer investigate problems nor answer questions about Ubuntu 21.10. We stopped supporting that release in July 2022. It's very unusual for a user to downgrade from 22.04 to 21.10. Consider migrating to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: In addition, downgrades are not supported by any release. Developers don't design the system to be downgraded and there's no testing or support for downgrades either.